# All the npm package not installed globally can't be executed directly

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, mocha.js

## Symptom:

I can't execute the npm packages directly that are not installed globally. But I can execute it by `npm scripts`. How to fix it?

For example:
I installed `gulp` under the project:

```
npm install gulp --save-dev
```

Then I try to execute it by

```
gulp
zsh: command not found: gulp
```

But if I add a `npm script` to `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require intelli-espower-loader && gulp test",
    "start": "gulp"
  },
```

Then run

```
npm start
```

It can get executed without problem.

P.S.
Same issue with the `mocha` package, I can't execute `mocha` directly but I can execute `npm test` without problem.

## Help Wanted:

What I can do to fix that issue?

## Notice:

I'm not saying that I want to execute them globally, I just want to execute them under the project.

I don't know where goes wrong, but they are executable not long ago, just don't work recently!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Ion's answer: You might need to add the path to the environment variables. In windows OS, it would be `%AppData%\npm`. For packages installed locally, you should be able to run them like

`.\node_modules\.bin\gulp`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute them globally install with the `-g` flag

`npm install gulp -g`

To run directly you could also do `./node_modules/.bin/gulp`

Answer (score 0):

That is because the package not installed globally doesn't create a reference in the root node_modules folder . If you want to specifically use the local installed version to run globally on terminal then go to you environment variables and set the path to  `./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js` or alternatively configure your npm to use the mentioned location as the gulp and execute `node_modules/.bin/gulp`

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. Install the executable modules globally:

   ```
   npm install -g gulp
   ```

   This is good if it's a tool you use often (for many different projects). For `gulp` specifically, the globally installed gulp will also check to see if the project has its own `gulp` installed (in node_modules) and run that version of `gulp`. This means that each project can have its own version of `gulp`. But not all tools have this feature.
2. Use `npx`:

   ```
   npx gulp
   ```

   Newer versions of `npm` ships with a command called `npx` which will search through your project's node_modules directory to find a module to execute. This means you don't need to install project specific tools globally. Apart form avoiding global installs of commands (which may or may not be a security issue) it also allows you to install project specific versions of tools.

   If your npm installation does not have npx you can install it from npm itself:

   ```
   npm install -g npx
   ```